# Ignoring database files at git commits

Tags: linux, django, git

I'm using Django to develop a website and I don't want to commit the database to the git repository. I've already included `database.db` to my `.gitignore` file, but it doesn't work: whenever I call `git status`, this file still appears in the "Changes not staged for commit" list. Is there any special configuration I have to do?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put .gitignore in the folder that contains database.db? Are you sure you called the ignore file .gitignore? (if you created it, for example, in notepad, it's probably called .gitignore.txt, which won't work).

Comment: Yes, Eran, it's in the right folder and it's called .gitignore. Besides, other files included in .gitignore are ignored, but it doesn't happen to the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your file is already tracked in GIT. Try:

```
git rm --cached [filename]
```